# Hoe does this function construct using window and undefined as arguments work?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the (function() {})() construct work and why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639180/how-does-the-function-construct-work-and-why-do-people-use-it)

Learning JavaScript, I came across this function:

```
(function(window, undefined){
  // …
})(window);
```

I’m wondering what type of function this is and how I can call it.

Comment: Agreed, I'm answering this only for the `window` and `undefined` arguments, which is not covered in the "duplicate" and IMO it actually makes sense to explain...

Answer (score 2):

It's a widely used pattern that allows you to have a local scope to declare all your variables, without pollute the global scope.

Is simply a FunctionExpression being immediately invoked, the `window` argument is used mostly to shorten the *identifier lookup* to the local scope.

In the browser environment `window` is a property of the global object, that points to the global object itself, if it exists on the local scope, resolving will be faster.

About the `undefined` argument, it is used to ensure that you can use it without worries, in some implementations (in fact all ECMAScript 3 based implementations) the `undefined` global property ( `window.undefined` ) is mutable, meaning that someone can change its value to e.g.:

```
window.undefined = true;
```

Breaking your script.