# Inject JavaScript variable as value in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I have a form where I add inputs dynamically. When I add a new input I increment a global `id` variable and concatenate it to the input's id so it will be unique. I also create a delete button for each input that should remove that input and himself (through removing the container `<div>` they are in). I do the remove process by adding an anonymous function to the delete button's click event via JQuery:

```
$('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){
    $('#inputcontainer' + id).remove();
});
```

The only problem with this solution that it isn't work in the way I excepted it. When I click any of the delete buttons it will delete the last input container because when I click, it executes the anonymous function and evaluate the `id` variable at that time, so the selected id will be the last input's id. So always the last input container will be deleted.

Is there a way to rewrite this function so when I add it to the click event, than it will evaluate the `id`, inject it and handle the selection as if it had been written like `#inputcontainer1`, `#inputcontainer2`, etc.

I can make this by adding the function's body to the button's `onclick()` event:

```
var newbutton = '<button id="deletebutton' + id + '" type="button" onclick="javascript:$(\'#inputcontainer' + id + '\').remove();">x</button>';
```

But is there a way doing this with the JQuery `click()` way?

Comment: simply $(this).remove()

Comment: It might be easier to do `$('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){ $(this).parent().remove(); )};`

Comment: That won't work, because totymedli is trying to remove an element that isn't the one that is clicked.

Comment: cannot you use a css class to add this function?

Comment: you can use the data attributes to store information and access it later:
//when creating
$("#deletebutton"+id).data("myid", 7);
//when accessing inside the click event of that button
var id = $(this).data("myid");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the specific question, you'd have to dig the id out of the DOM:

```
$('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace('deletebutton','');
    $('#inputcontainer' + id).remove();
});
```

You could also store it as data when you create the delete button:

```
<button data-id="1" id="deletebutton1">

$('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $('#inputcontainer' + id).remove();
});
```

Note that in both of these cases, `id` is a string, not an integer.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write, to the letter.

Comment: @andy this is Stack Overflow, so I assume you're going to write it anyway? ;-)

Comment: Wow this solution is even better than what I wanted to do. This way I doesn't even need to inject variable values. Your solution is much dynamic. The only problem is that you need to give a second argument to `replace()`, otherwise it will return `"undefined1"`, `"undefined2"`, etc.
`$(this).attr("id").replace('deletebutton', '');` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> *When I click any of the delete buttons it will delete **the last input container** [...]*

If your 1st snippet is inside a loop, `id` probably isn't being scoped to each iteration. So, by the time one of the `click()` events is triggered and it's trying to use `.remove()`, `id` will have already been set to the last value given while looping.

You can use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1639180) to create an additional `function` scope for keeping a different `id` for each iteration (ref: [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)).

```
/* loop */ {
    var id = ...;

    (function (id) {
        $('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){
            $('#inputcontainer' + id).remove();
        });
    })(id);
}
```

Though, for future reference, ECMAScript 6 is adding [block scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which should allow for:

```
/* loop */ {
    let id = ...;

    $('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){
        $('#inputcontainer' + id).remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

If the container isn't a direct parent and doesn't have a class you could do:

```
$('#deletebutton' + id).click(function(){
    var idNum = $(this).attr("id").replace('deletebutton','');
    $("#inputcontainer"+idNum).remove();
});
```

If you've got appropriate classes (or can add them), this would be best:

```
$(document).on("click",".deleteButton",function() {
    $(this).parents(".inputContainer").remove();
});
```

Comment: i think with just using class we can do, no id/ID needed !