# what does function () {} mean when assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that functions are objects in javascript, and that functions can be assigned to variables. I am also aware of this question: [How does the (function() {})() construct work and why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639180/how-does-the-function-construct-work-and-why-do-people-use-it).

But I would like to know precisely what does it mean in this context:
https://github.com/zsolt/retwis-nodejs/blob/master/domain.js#L43

```
User = function(){}
```

This line is followed by the declaration of some member functions (methods?) of the "supposed" `User` object.
It seems there is no other explanation answer here in SO.

Comment: It seems like creation of the new empty class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally

Comment: isn't it just a no op function, almost like the null object pattern.

Comment: In your case, the assignment of a function is just rubbish. It's never called. It should have been a plain object `var User = {};`

Comment: @Bergi: The function is called (https://github.com/zsolt/retwis-nodejs/blob/master/domain.js#L68 + others).

Comment: @Matt: Ah thanks, I overlooked that. However given that `User` instances neither have initialisation nor methods, an object literal would've fitted better there as well (assuming all the methods really should be static).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means `User` is a function that takes no inputs, has no side effects and returns nothing.

Most likely it is a class constructor and methods will be added to it later. `User.foo = function() { /* ... */}` would imply a static method, so this is more like a utilities class if you're used to thinking in Java architecture.

You should look up pseudo-classical inheritance in Javascript. Analogizing to Java, the code would be adding *static* methods to the `User` *class*, not object.

I'm still pretty convinced the code is following Java class patterns because the writer would prefer `User` to be a constructor that can be instantiated, has static methods, and has no instance methods (that I saw), over an object with properties that are functions. You are right that this is circuitous, but it's what the writer would do if they are a Java developer. It does have the advantage that instance methods may be added to `User` *later* with little client-code impact but I see no evidence this will happen to `User` (I didn't look long).

By the way, I deduced this because `CapitalizedNames` for functions implies it should be called with `new` in Javascript engineering in general, which implies it's a class. Figuring out why a class might be preferable just has to do with Java experience.

Comment: That's not the case, functions are added on `User` function, not on `User.prototype`. Using a function here seems to be wrong, when you could simply use `{}`.

Comment: Thanks, I "come" from Java world too, and the explanation you gave makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to create an object in Javascript is:

`function user(config) {
  this.config = config;
  ...
}
User = new user(config);`

It uses `this` context (and concept). This format is used if you want to create named properties and/or methods.

If you don't need to create `this` context you may use just following:

`User = function(){}`

Here the constructor function is anonymous and doesn't create any context. For the same reason the `new` keyword is not needed.