# Anonymous function execution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why if I have

```
function(){...}()
```

does not work while when I put inside brackets like

```
(function(){...}())
```

it works?

Comment: The first is a function declaration which is a statement. The second is a function expression. Only the value that an expression produces can be executed.

Comment: Also relevant: [How does the (function() {})() construct work and why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1639180) | [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859)